# How to create a set of two elements: Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have two rectangles on my canvas, now I want them to snap together if I drag one of them ontop of the other. I guess I will need to use set() but not sure how. This is what I got so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var paper = Raphael(20, 20, 5000, 5000);

var rect1 = paper.rect(50, 50, 50, 50).attr({
    fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
    stroke: "none",
    opacity: .5,
});

var rect2 = paper.rect(50, 50, 50, 50).attr({
    fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
    stroke: "none",
    opacity: .5,
});

var rectStart = function() {
        this.ox = this.attr("x");
        this.oy = this.attr("y");
        this.attr({opacity: 1});
    },
    rectMove = function(dx, dy) {
        this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
    },
    rectUp = function(){
        this.attr({opacity: .5});
    };


rect1.drag(rectMove, rectStart, rectUp);
rect2.drag(rectMove, rectStart, rectUp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write the logic inside the `rectUp` method.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7bhm72L/2/)

```
var paper = Raphael(20, 20, 5000, 5000);

var rect1 = paper.rect(50, 50, 50, 50).attr({
    fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
    stroke: "none"
});
rect1.track_x = 50;
rect1.track_y = 50;

var rect2 = paper.rect(150, 50, 50, 50).attr({
    fill: "#aa9988",
    stroke: "none"
});
rect2.track_x = 150;
rect2.track_y = 50;

function rectStart() {
}

function rectMove(dx, dy) {
    this.attr({x: this.track_x + dx, y: this.track_y + dy});
}

function rectUp() {

    this.track_x = this.attr("x");
    this.track_y = this.attr("y");
    var currentDragRect, idleRect;
    if(this == rect1) {
        currentDragRect = rect1;
        idleRect = rect2;
    } else {
        currentDragRect = rect2;
        idleRect = rect1;
    }
    /*
    r11   r12     currentDragRect
    r21   r22     idleRect
    */
    //r11 <= r22 && r21 <= r12
    //50 is width and height
    if( (currentDragRect.track_x <= (idleRect.track_x + 50)) &&
        (idleRect.track_x <= (currentDragRect.track_x + 50)) ) {

        if( (currentDragRect.track_y <= (idleRect.track_y + 50)) &&
            (idleRect.track_y <= (currentDragRect.track_y + 50)) ) {

            //p.translate(300, 100);
            alert('Done  ' + idleRect.track_x);
            currentDragRect.attr({x: idleRect.track_x, y: idleRect.track_y});
            //currentDragRect.transform('t' + idleRect.track_x + ','+ idleRect.track_y);

        }

    }
}

rect1.drag(rectMove, rectStart, rectUp);
rect2.drag(rectMove, rectStart, rectUp);
```

I also tried with using [Element.onDragOver](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.onDragOver) but it [didnt work](http://jsfiddle.net/n7bhm72L/1/) as expected. So as said in the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738491/raphael-js-attr-function-sets-wrong-value/32743655#32743655) tracking co-ordinates will helps to solve this kind of problem.